# Issue applying purrr::map() inside nested dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, purrr

I'm working through chapter 25 "Many Models" of Hadley Wickham's *R for Data Science* https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html , however I'm running into issues in recreating the examples in 25.2.2.

Here's what I have so far (and what's working):

```r
require(gapminder); require(tidyverse); require(broom); require(modelr)

by_country <- gapminder %>% group_by(country,continent) %>% nest()
head(by_country)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  country     continent data             
  <fct>       <fct>     <list>           
1 Afghanistan Asia      <tibble [12 × 4]>
2 Albania     Europe    <tibble [12 × 4]>
3 Algeria     Africa    <tibble [12 × 4]>
4 Angola      Africa    <tibble [12 × 4]>
5 Argentina   Americas  <tibble [12 × 4]>
6 Australia   Oceania   <tibble [12 × 4]>
```

Then defining the `lm()` to apply to each of country's set of data:

```
country_model <- function(df) {
  lm(lifeExp ~ year, data = df)
}
```

And then this next line doesn't work:

```
by_country <- by_country %>%
  mutate(model = map(data,country_model))
```

with error message

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'lifeExp' not found
```

Despite, to my eyes, what I've written being the same as what's appeared in Hadley's chapter.

I'm unsure if this is a recent issue that used to work, as someone else has apparently had an issue with the example: https://github.com/hadley/r4ds/issues/766 (with no solution)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've got dplyr v0.8.3 and purrr v0.3.2 and this runs just fine: I'm getting a data frame with a list-column of nested data and a list-column of `lm` objects. I think I'm a little behind on my updates though

Comment: What is the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: @Parfait good idea, though it results in the following error:
Error in UseMethod("unnest_") : 
  no applicable method for 'unnest_' applied to an object of class "list"

Comment: @Aurèle my sessioninfo is linked here: https://pastebin.com/t0WhrURN

Comment: I am able to run the example. The only difference is that I call libraries instead of `require`, i.e. `library(gapminder) library(tidyverse) library(broom)
library(modelr)`

Comment: You have older versions of `dplyr` and `purrr`. Try upgrading. Please note, because of the rapid development of `tidyverse` and its built changes, previous code that once worked can stop working and newer code may not work. This is one of the challenges with *tidy* environments.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to redefine "by_country" twice.

```
country_model <- function(df) {
lm(lifeExp ~ year, data = df)
}

by_country <- gapminder %>% 
group_by(country,continent) %>% 
nest()%>%
mutate(model = map(data,country_model))
```

Answer (score 1):

The group_by + nest combo can be replaced with nest_by, only thing different is the results is grouped rowwise so you would need to put functions in a list. Something like this:

```
results <- gapminder %>% 
    nest_by(continent, country) %>% 
    mutate(model = list(lm(lifeExp ~ year, data = data)))
```